# What is the difference between composer in ballerina and composer used for laravel installation?

Tags: laravel, wso2, ballerina, ballerina-composer

I have installed the ballerina-tools-0.95.6 some days ago. It uses composer to  provide a browser based developer tool. Now I try to install laravel. The instalation guide directs me to install composer and use that to install laravel. Now I have a confusion. Are both composers same or different? If both are different ,then what are the differences?What are the roles of these both composers?

Comment: Judging by the docs of Ballerina, they're different. Composer is a package manager, Balerina composer is an editor.

Comment: Yes, I have got a better understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're two completely different things. :)

Ballerina and PHP are different programming languages. While both have tools called "composer", the Ballerina Composer is a browser-based Ballerina program manager, and the PHP Composer is a dependency manager for PHP.

Laravel is built in PHP and has absolutely nothing to do with Ballerina. The composer you want is available here: https://getcomposer.org

Comment: Yes Ballerina is a completely different language which is optimized for integration. Ballerina Composer is a graphical editor and a source editor to program, run, debug ballerina programs.

Comment: Yes, Ballerina composer helps to run its graphical editor and php composer is used to install laravel . I have got a clear picture. Thanks